# how to connect to an external API using python?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to write a script which takes the usernames from an excel sheet in a loop and then connect to an external API of a website and get the user ID's from it and give gave the response in the excel sheet. Please help me with an example code.

I need help on two things:-

1:- How to read a particular column elements from an excel sheet

2:- Write a code in the script which uses an API of a website to feed the excel sheet usernames in it in a loop and retrieve the user ID's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading the information from the excel sheet take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

For retrieving the user IDs it depends on the API itself so you would need to provide more information.

Additionally, you might want to look at this [Python library for the Instagram API](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram).

Comment: Thank you for the help! Here is what I actually want to do. I have an excel sheet with a column username with data. I want to feed those usernames to the instagram API https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN         and recieve the user id's and feed it back to my excel sheet

Comment: @rohitnair the site ARK has linked to in the answer below provides a good introduction on how to make the API calls you want.

Comment: Okay. I will refer it. Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://www.python-excel.org/) contains pointers to the best information available about working with Excel files in the Python programming language.

[This site](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-intermediate-en-6zbLp/0/1?curriculum_id=50ecbb9b71204640240001bf) will show you how to use APIs with python.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Here is what I actually want to do.         I have an excel sheet with a column username with data. I want to feed those usernames to the instagram API                                 api.instagram.com/v1/users{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN and recieve the user id's and feed it back to my excel shee

Comment: Thanks guys for the previous answers. Now I can connect to the Excel file and perform read and write operations. But one thing still remains unclear even after referring the sites for API connection. How will I give the username as a parameter an receive the necessary info. Can you please help me with a start up code or something?